# Where is the Google Sign-In configuration file?

Tags: google-signin

It's August of 2022, and I want to integrate Google Sign-In into my Unity game. I believe [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-signin-unity) plugin is the latest one to use for both iOS and Android. It often refers to Google's documentation for the initial setup, but one of the steps says:

> **Get a Google Sign-In configuration file**:
> This file contains the client-side information needed to use Google Sign-in. The details on how to do this are documented on the Developer website.

I don't see anywhere to go to get this configuration file at the "[Developer website](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#get-config)". I have a credentials.json for Android and a credentials.plist for iOS, but I can't find this configuration file that I need to edit.

Does anyone know where to find this?
Thanks!
Matt

P.S. - I notice in the setup that I need to import a unitypackage, but that package is not provided in the github project...so that's another thing...help?!

Comment: that repo hasnt been touched in five years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The config file you are probably looking for may be the client secrete json file downloaded from [google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/) after creating web application credentials.

That being said.

First of you should note that that library hasn't been updated in four years.  I have never used it but lets do some digging.

So [Google Sign-In Unity Plugin](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-signin-unity) says

> To authenticate you need to create credentials on the API console for your
> application. The steps to do this are available on
> [Google Sign-In for Android](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start)
> or as part of Firebase configuration.
> In order to access ID tokens or server auth codes, you also need to configure
> a web client ID.

Which takes us to [Google Sign-In for Android](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start)  At the top of that page you can see

[image]

Which leads me to believe that this library for some reason was using the old "Google Sign-In JavaScript Platform Library for web".  No idea why I would assume unity being C# it would have used one of the C# libraries.

So if it was using the old JavaScript lib then its not going to work as you need to switch to using. [Google Identity Services](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web)

You may also want to note that by the look of a lot of the comments since Google shut down the JavaScript signin in around May.  It doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: For the fun of it lets ping one of the googles that did the project [Twitter question](https://twitter.com/LindaLawtonDK/status/1554857751762931712)

Comment: That all makes perfect sense, thank you so much for the breakdown. I think perhaps I was being too ambitious, as long as I can use the Google Play Games services for iOS and Android, that is the way to go I think. You saved me a lot of time.

Comment: remember to accept the answer if it helps.  it will increase your reputation as well